# Three digit or a character validation regex is not working

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a legacy code base where regex validation is being done like this:

```
string regexString = null;
      string matchingString = null;

// Code to populate this two
if (matchingString.Equals(regex.Match(matchingString).Value))
      {
        //success code
      }
      else
      {
        //failure code    
      }
```

I cannot make any change in this code. But I can set the regexString by setting a particular value.
Now that you know the situation, here is the problem:

I want to validate a given string for the following conditions:

1. It can be a one digit string.
2. It can be two digit string.
3. It can be three digit string.
4. It can have the value * (but then no numbers with this.)

e.g:

Valid values are: `1`, `27`, `453`, `*` .

Invalid values are: `4563`, `5*`, `54*` .

I am using the regular expression string as `[0-9]{0,3}|\*`. This works perfect for the numbers but failing miserably for `*`.
Surprisingly (for me),`[0-9]{3}|\*` validates any three digit number (fixed length) and *. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regular expression is failing is because of the way `|` works!

When presented with the input `*`, the regular expression works as follows:

- Start at index 0
- Can I match [0-9]{0} here? Yes!
- Can I be greedy and match [0-9]{1} here? No!
- I've matched the left hand side of `|`
- I'm done! My first match is `""`

It is NOT going "OK, I've matched zero digits, but I'd better check to see if I can match the star instead.

Thus `Value` is `""`, and your enclosing code then realises that `"" != *`. " and goes down the `else` branch.

How to fix this?

- To be lazy, just put the `*` before the `|` and the `[0-9]{0-3}` after, `@"\*|[0-9]{0,3}"` - this makes it match the star first if it can.
- Replace the `{0,3}` with `{1,3}` and add a second `|` with nothing after, `@"[0-9]{1,3}|\*|"` - this makes it clear that you're matching one-to-three digits OR star OR nothing.
- (Or do a [Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20071556/215380) and include the `^` and `$`, forcing the regular expression to match the whole string - this is how the regular expression *should* work but it makes a mockery of the containing code. Which is fair enough, the containing code is pretty terrible.)

Answer (score 4):

did you try this syntax:

```
string regexString = @"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}|\*)$";
```

or

```
string regexString = "^(?:[0-9]{1,3}|\\*)$";
```

Comment: In this case, it looks like the containing code is meant to be doing the job of the '^' and '$' , by checking that the whole string equals the match value.

Comment: @Rawling: indeed, but is the regex engine informed of this?

Comment: I don't think it really needs to care, at least for this particular regular expression. The regular expression `[0-9]{1,3}|\*` should match the entire input iff the entire input is one to three digits or a star. I agree it's a weird way of doing it, and it would fail with a non-greedy expression, but for this particular example I can't see why OP's expression is failing.

Comment: @Rawling: I think that the OP problem is a type of string/escape problem. If I asked this naive question, it's because of regex engine performance, that is more efficient when the pattern is anchored. However, the result will be the same

Comment: I've isolated why OP's regex "doesn't work", but the real issue is the enclosing code and to be honest your answer is the real way it should be done.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, but are you sure the OP want to allow an empty string?

Comment: Good point, I assumed OP knew what he was doing by putting `{0,3}` rather than `{1,3}` - otherwise that's the *really obvious* reason his code isn't working as expected!